# How to efficiently INSERT a dict whose keys match the table fields?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, mariadb

I very rarely use SQL with Python and recently needed to write some simple data in a table.
I use MariaDB but I think my question is relevant for other SQL based DBs.

I have a `dict` such as `a = {'one": 1, 'two': 2 }` that I need to `INSERT` into a table.
Following the [documentation of the Python connector](https://mariadb.com/fr/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/), I went for

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO mytable (one,two) VALUES (?, ?)", 
    (a['one'], b['two']))
```

**Note that the names of the fields of the table correspond to the keys of the `dict`.**

In reality, I had about 10 keys (which I still typed by hand the same way as above) but I could have ended up with a hundred.

Before I start to reinvent the wheel: is there a consensual way to insert such data into the DB?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Either use an ORM like [Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org), or just do it the hard way. If you find a connector that uses named placeholders your life might be a little easier, but you still need to be careful when writing queries. The good news is unless you need > 100 queries per second, just about any approach you take will probably be fine.

Comment: I also think you mean "convenient" rather than "consensual". At least I hope you do!

Comment: @tadman: I did mean *consensual*. I now had a look at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consensual and realized that in (British?) English, it seems to have a strong sexual (legal) connotation. Merriam Webster provides a meaning that is closer to the French one - something everyone agrees upon (no matter the topic) (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consensual)

Comment: Actually I think you want to say "Is there a consensus about the way to insert such data into the DB"

Comment: @Nick: this is another way to say it. If you look at Merriam-Webster, their example is *a consensual contract*. This corresponds to my *consensual way*

Comment: The way you're using it is really, really off the mark. "Consensual" directly implies "consent" and it is used to describe inter-personal actions and relationships. "Conventional" or "by consensus" is a proper way of phrasing it.